# Nextjs route handler search params are undefined when deployed on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, app-router

I am using the app router and have an API route at the path `/api/nfl/gameData/route.ts`

I am trying to access this route from this page `/nfl/game/[gameId]/page.tsx`

My route is defined like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);
    const gameId = searchParams.get('gameId');

    console.log(`Game ID in api route: ${gameId}`);
    const gameDataResponse = await fetch(
        `https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/summary?event=${gameId}`
      );
    
      if (!gameDataResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch game data");
      }
    
    const gameData = await gameDataResponse.json();

    // other api calls and formatting before returning

    return NextResponse.json({"gameData": gameData);
}
```

I am calling the API route like this:

```
"use client"

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function TeamPage({ params }: { params: { gameId: string } }) {
  console.log(params.gameId);
  const { data, isLoading } = useSwr(
    `http://${BASE_URL}/api/nfl/gameData?gameId=${params.gameId}`,
    fetcher
  );
```

The search params work properly and console log correctly in both files in dev and production when running on my local machine. However, when deployed on Vercel, the search params in the route return undefined. I can, however, access other routes that are not dependent on search params. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: I'm just why do you have gameId in your route, and yet you have gameId in searchparams

Comment: I'm not sure. I wanted to have the api route in the same folder, but I couldn't get the gameId from the url into the route. I'm rearranging it now but it shouldn't be the cause of the problem

Comment: in Next 13 router.query has been removed (due to the new app router) and replaced with useSearchParams(); hook instead, so you can use it like this: